# Loop over a Numpy array with Cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

Let `a` and `b` be two `numpy.float` arrays of length 1024, defined with

```
cdef numpy.ndarray a
cdef numpy.ndarray b
```

I notice that:

```
cdef int i
for i in range(1024):
    b[i] += a[i]
```

is considerably slower than:

```
b += a
```

Why?

I really need to be able to loop manually over arrays.

Comment: You're read and followed http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html?  I mean I doubt you are going to beat b+=a in terms of speed, but what kind of speeds are you actually getting?

Comment: The latter is still using Numpy's own ufunc loops which can include a number of enhancements depending on how your Numpy was compiled.  The former does not, and is further harmed by slow indexing of the ndarray objects; the link @ballsdotballs provided discusses this and how to fix it.

Comment: Just a side comment : is `cdef float x`  a 32-bit or 64-bit float?   Which cdef type will work with numpy.float32, numpy.float64? I looked at the doc but didn't find precise correspondance.

Comment: For future reference, I checked : `float <=> numpy.float32`,      `double <=> numpy.float64 = numpy.float`

Comment: `nditer` handles loops like this nicely.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.nditer.html#putting-the-inner-loop-in-cython

Comment: Memoryviews can also perform this kind of assignment efficiently, http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference will be smaller if you tell Cython the data type and the number of dimensions for `a` and `b`:

```
cdef numpy.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] a, b
```

Although the difference will be smaller, you won't beat `b += a` because this is using NumPy's SIMD-boosted functions (which will perform depending if your CPU supports SIMD).